How to find the vector bundle defining a projective bundle?
Assume I am working with (smooth projectives) varieties over a field (mainly $k=\mathbb{C}$).
Let $V$ be a variety and $\mathcal{E}$ a vector bundle of rank $r+1$ with $W=\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$ the associated projective bundle. My question is the following (I think it is quite impossible to answer it in the general case, but maybe someone knows something).
Question : Assume I only know $W$, how can I find the vector bundle $\mathcal{E}$.
(Side note : I know that $\mathcal{E}$ is not unique, but in my case $V$ will be a Fano variety with Picard rank $1$, so I hope the non-canonicity problem should not be so much important.)
In my situation I am studying an introduction to Mukai pairs, so the existence of this stucture is assumed, but not so much is known on the base space $V$. Let $\pi : W \rightarrow V$ be the projection morphism.
Furthermore due to my hypothesis I have a bundle $\mathcal{K}$ whose restriction to each fiber of $\pi$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}(1)$. So, the base change formula gives me a vector bundle $\mathcal{F}=\pi_* \mathcal{K}$ (of the correct dimension) which should be a good candidate.
Now I try to prove that $W\simeq \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{F})$. It seems clear that $\mathcal{K}$ is a quotient bundle of $\pi^*\mathcal{F}=\pi^*\pi_*\mathcal{K}$. So the universal property of projective varieties gives me a natural morphism $f : W \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{F})$. But here I don't see how to conclude.
To use the universal property in the other direction, I would have to construct a quotient line bundle of $\phi^*\mathcal{E}$ where $\phi$ is the projection for the projectivisation of $\mathcal{F}$. But I don't know how to do this because $\mathcal{E}$ is still unknown at this point of the proof. An other idea would be to prove directly that $f$ is an isomorphism, but again I don't know why.
Any clue would be helpful, thanks.

The idea is correct, though, depending on your convention about what $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$ is, you might need to dualize $\mathcal{F}$. Anyway, $\mathcal{K}$ is not a subbundle of $\pi^\pi_\mathcal{K}$, but its quotient bundle. And the statement altogether is well known.

@Sasha Yes I mean a quotient, sorty for the mistake I am going to edit the post. But when you say that it is well known, what are you referring to ?

That must be in many places: for instance it may be in Fulton's "Intersection theory".

I think I have found a formal proof. For later use I will answer my own question. I keep the same notations as before.
In fact, as $\mathcal{E}$ is locally free, we have an isomorphism $\text{Sym}^n (\mathcal{E})\simeq \pi_* (\mathcal{O}_{\pi}(n))$. I will just use the case $n=1$. By adjunction formula, it comes from the natural surjection $\pi^*\mathcal{E}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\pi}(1)$ given by the universal property of projective bundles. The fact that it is an isomorphism is explained in the section 27.21 of Stacks.
So I have just to prove that the line bundle $\mathcal{K}$ is isomorphic to this line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\pi}(1)$. Here I start using the fact that $W$ is a projective bundle over a Mukai pair.
First I will prove that $\mathcal{K}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\pi}(1)$ have the same class modulo numerical equivalence.  As $\rho(W)=2$, we just need to check they have the same intersection product for a fiber of both fibrations. For the first one it is clear because I choose $\mathcal{K}$ to be the tautologocal bundle for this fibration, and for the second one I said that I already prove this point.
Then as $W$ is Fano, rational and numerical equivalences are the same, so we have $\mathcal{K}\simeq \mathcal{O}_{\pi}(1)$. So the proof is over.
I consider this attempt as a good solution to my question, but if someone find a solution without using the assumption on $W$, feel free to write it.
